# Update React when Data in Object in Store has changed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've found lots of similar problems, can't seem to sort my case

I have a component that won't re-render when data changes.

When `MODE` changes, which is a string, the entity re-renders and updates.

When `hotspot.description` changes, it won't update.

I can see the description has changed in the store, I can console log the changes all the way to this component.

However I just can't get this component to update when the `description` changes in `hotspot`.

Any clues!?

Connected

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    mode: state.admin.hotspot.mode,
    hotspot: state.admin.hotspot.edit,
  }
}
```

Pure

```
export default class HotspotRenderer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      hotspot:props.hotspot,
      mode:props.mode,
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      hotspot : nextProps.hotspot,
      mode: nextProps.mode,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {hotspot,mode} = this.state

    const isEditingText = hotspot && mode === HOTSPOT_EDIT_MODE.TEXT
    const html = hotspot != null ? ReactHtmlParser(draftToHtml(hotspot.description)) : null

    return (
      <div>
        {
          isEditingText &&
          <Container>
            <div className={`hotspot-renderer hotspot${hotspot.id} hotspot-text-default`}><div>{html}</div></div>
          </Container>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

admin.state.hotspot

```
const initialState = {
  isDraggingNewHotspot: false,
  edit:null,
  mode:null,
}

export function hotspot(prevState=initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case START_ADD_HOTSPOT:      return { ...prevState, isDraggingNewHotspot: true }
  case FINISH_ADD_HOTSPOT:     return { ...prevState, isDraggingNewHotspot: false }
  case ADD_HOTSPOT:            return { ...prevState,  mode: HOTSPOT_EDIT_MODE.DRAG}
  case EDIT_HOTSPOT:           return { ...prevState,  edit: action.hotspot}
  case FINISH_EDIT_HOTSPOT:    return { ...prevState,  edit: null}
  case EDIT_HOTSPOT_MODE:      return { ...prevState, mode: action.mode }
  case UPDATE_HOTSPOT:         return { ...prevState, edit : action.hotspot }
  case GO_TO_EDIT_SCENE:       return { ...prevState, edit :null,mode :null }
  case UPDATE_SCENE_HOTSPOT_SUCCESS: return { ...prevState, edit: processUpdatedHotspot(prevState.edit,action.payload) }
  default:                     return prevState
  }
}

function processUpdatedHotspot(prev,update){

  if(!prev)
    return null

  if(!prev.id)
    prev.id = update.id

  return prev
}
```

Here is where the description is edited

```
  updateHotspotDescription(description){
    let hotspot = this.state.hotspot
    hotspot.description = description
    hotspot.imageUpdateRequired = true
    this.setState({hotspot : hotspot})
    this.state.onUpdateHotspot(hotspot)
  }
```

This is dispatched whenever text is changed, via a draft-js editor.

The state is updated with the changes, and another entity is aware of them.

Comment: You're probably mutating the nested objects when updating the `hotspot` value, can you show your dispatched action ?

Comment: could you show the structure of `state.admin.hotspot`

Comment: I think @Dyo is right - `processUpdatedHotspot` is mutating `prev`, which is part of state.

Comment: Thanks I tried removing that.. but ti didn't make any difference. Will have another look. EDIT - yes. it makes no difference.

Comment: Curious as to why the component has state. It appears to exactly mirror the props. Could you leave off componentWillReceiveProps and the constructor?

Comment: Thanks @TrueWill I've tried removing both of those and the component still works.. but still does not update when the store updates.. very strange

Comment: We'll need to see where you dispatch the UPDATE_HOTSPOT action, you are probably mutating `edit.description` there.

Comment: Yes it's dispatched when the edit.description changes, to update the state with the new description. Is that not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to follow the [Immutable pattern](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) to update your value, even before passing it to redux (see updating nesting objects in the link).

So before sending `hotspot.edit` to your reducer be sure to update the nested `description` object following the immutable pattern like this :

```
updateHotspotDescription(description){
    const hotspot = { 
        ...this.state.hotspot,
        description, // shorthand for description: description
        imageUpdateRequired: true,
    };
    this.setState({ hotspot });
    this.state.onUpdateHotspot(hotspot);
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you so much. Works perfectly, I'll read up further on this.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to question yourself, are you sure your `action` it's being actually taken?

Any non-case in the `switch` statement will return the previous state, therefore It's normal that It won't re-render.

Some tips to follow to verify if your `redux` state it's being updated:

- Make sure your `constants` are imported correctly in your `actions` and in your `reducer`
- Make sure the triggered `action` it's being properly taken by the reducer
- Log the next state in your `reducer` before your return it, so you can be sure that the next state is the correct one

Follow this steps and let me know if your problem persists